# In the ground state properties of electron gas, is $V$ the volume of all the metal or the volume of a cell of the lattice?

Tags: electrons, solid-state-physics, metals, ground-state

In the ground state properties of electron gas (Sommerfeld theory), is $V$ the volume of all the metal or the volume of a cell of the lattice?
I thought the latter because the Born—von Karman boundary condition makes me recall the periodicity of lattice.
I'm talking about  V in

$$
\psi_{\boldsymbol{k}}(\boldsymbol{r})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}} e^{i \boldsymbol{k} \cdot \boldsymbol{r}}.
$$

Comment: Where exactly did you take the equation from? Normalization depends on context. It may have been a normalization to unit per unit cell or to unit over the crystal or something else.

Comment: I took the equation from "Solid State Physics, Ashcroft, Mermin"

Answer (score 0):

[The equations here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearly_free_electron_model#Introduction_-_a_heuristic_argument) say that "where we integrate in $\mathbf{r}$ over a single lattice cell" and puts the limits of the integral as $\Omega_r$. The equation there for time-independent part of the wave function is
$$\phi_\mathbf{k}(\mathbf{r}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\Omega_r}}e^{\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{V}}e^{\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}$$

So apparently the $V = \Omega_r$ is the volume of a **single** cell.

Edit: Alright, considering the crystal is finite, we can actually integrate over the whole lattice, then the $\Omega_r$ would be the the total volume. So, as ruslan has told, it depends on how you define things.

Comment: Total volume does make sense, since as soon as you use Born-von Karman conditions, you already admit that your crystal is finite (closed but still finite).

Comment: @Ruslan Maybe, I am not very accustomed to the concept of Born–von Karman conditions. But yes, if the crystal is finite, it makes more sense to use the total volume I guess.

Comment: @Ruslan Could please explain a bit more this "as soon as you use Born-von Karman conditions, you already admit that your crystal is finite (closed but still finite)"?

Comment: @JBach in an infinite crystal, Born–von Karman BCs don't make sense: you don't have values of the wavefunction and its derivative to match. The only BC which makes sense in this case is boundedness of the wavefunction at infinity. So by introducing BvK conditions, you admit that your crystal is finite.